# how can I validate if good analytics is counting review with ajax request

Tags: google-analytics

I have installed the google analytics in our e-commerce site using google tag manager. From the product detail page you can click on the colors to see the same product in the different colors. I implemented this using ajax so the page load is not required. I was curious if the google analytics will count as multiple reviews a user clicks on the different colors or do I need to explicitly call something in order for the GA to count as multiple reviews.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that depends how and what kind of GA you've implemented.

To implement analytics, you have to specify a trigger for the analytics tag. That trigger normally determines if a tag is fired or not.

If you used a page load trigger, then the tag will only be triggered on the real page load. And it won't be triggered on your ajax manipulations.

With only one exception: if you used the GA4 config tag, you had this checkbox there:

[image]

The checkbox doesn't only send the pageview on config load, it keeps sending pageviews on every history change. Therefore, if your ajax causes history change and you use the GA4 config tag, then you're getting pageviews.

But this is theory. You can just go and check. Open your network tab, filter the request by `collect` and see what's sent when. Or alternatively, install the adswerve datalayer debugger and it will log whatever is sent whenever it's sent into the console in a very neat, clean way. This is how it works on this page:

[image]